# Separar expresión matemática con expresiones regulares en Java

Tags: java, regex

Necesito, dada una expresión, llegar a una colección que contenga en orden cada número y operador por separado, uno tras otro.

```
"1000000.315+5.8/(6.0+1-8*2.0)"
```

deber producir una lista como

```
1000000.315
+
5.8
/
(
6.0
+
1
-
8
*
2.0
```

Si utilizo split de la siguiente forma solo me extrae los operadores:

```
expr_lst = buffer.split("([0-9\\.]+)");
```

Y en cambio si uso `"(?!\\.)\\W"` como expresión, solo los números.

¿Podrían ayudarme?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1. Split**

Con [`String.split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-), los separadores siempre van a quedar fuera del resultado. Hay una forma sencilla. Aunque no la usaría, empiezo explicando por acá.

Se puede hacer que el `split` sea sobre la ***posición*** antes o después de un operador matemático. Al ser una *posición*, no estaríamos consumiendo ningún caracter, por lo que el resultado incluiría a todo el string en el resultado.

Para coincidir con la posición, usamos **[inspecciones](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#special)** (*[lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)*).

Así, para la posición previa a un símbolo matemático, usamos una inspección positiva (*positive lookahead*), cuya sintaxis es `(?=`…`)`.
Nos queda: `(?=[-+*/()])`,

Y para la posición posterior a un símbolo matemático, usamos una inspección hacia atrás positiva (*positive lookbehind*), cuya sintaxis es `(?<=`…`)`.
Nos queda: `(?<=[-+*/()])`.

Y ambas opciones unidas en una expresión, nos queda:

```
texto.split("(?=[-+*/()])|(?<=[-+*/()])")
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/ZMKc9r

---

**2. Coincidir**

Pero el anterior no es un regex "eficiente" desde la perspectiva de las iteraciones que ocurren a nivel del motor de expresiones regulares. Además, no se lleva bien con espacios entre símbolos.. Es mucho más intuitivo -y cómo lo haría yo- olvidarse del split, y buscar las coincidencias que nos interesan. Es decir, buscamos que el regex ***coincida*** con:

1. Números

   ```
   [\d.]+
   ```
2. o Símbolos

   ```
   [-+*/()]
   ```

Y de esta forma los vamos agregando a la colección (o el tipo de datos que prefieras), con:

```
[\d.]+|[-+*/()]
```

- <sub><sup>Recordemos que en Java, para pasarlo como String se debe escapar la barra: `"[\\d.]+|[-+*/()]"`.</sup></sub>

En el código, la forma de buscar todas las coincidencias de un regex es con [`Matcher.find()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find--), y obteniendo el texto que coincidió con [`Matcher.group()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group--).

Código:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
```

```
//variables
final String texto = "1000000.315+5.8/(6.0+1-8*2.0)";
//variables para el regex
final String regex = "[\\d.]+|[-+*/()]";
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(texto);
//usamos este tipo para el resultado, pero puede ser el que prefieras
final List<String> resultado = new ArrayList<String>();

//buscamos todas las coincidencias
while (matcher.find()) {
    //agregando una por una a la lista
    //  matcher.group() devuelve la coincidencia del último matcher.find()
    resultado.add(matcher.group());
}
```

```
//podemos imprimir la lista
System.out.println(resultado);
```

Resultado:

```
[1000000.315, +, 5.8, /, (, 6.0, +, 1, -, 8, *, 2.0, )]
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/ujoNmV

---

**3. Analizar diferenciando números de símbolos**

Tomando el regex anterior:

```
[\d.]+|[-+*/()]
```

Podemos usar un grupo (encerrar entre paréntesis) en una parte que nos interese:

```
([\d.]+)|[-+*/()]
```

Y así, diferenciaríamos si es un número o un símbolo:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
```

```
final String texto = "1000000.315+5.8/(6.0+1-8*2.0)";
final String regex = "([\\d.]+)|[-+*/()]";
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(texto);

while (matcher.find())
{
    if (matcher.group(1) != null) //si se capturó algo en el grupo 1 (el primer conjunto de paréntesis)
    {
        System.out.println("Número:  " + matcher.group());
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Símbolo: " + matcher.group());
    }
}
```

Resultado:

```
Número:  1000000.315
Símbolo: +
Número:  5.8
Símbolo: /
Símbolo: (
Número:  6.0
Símbolo: +
Número:  1
Símbolo: -
Número:  8
Símbolo: *
Número:  2.0
Símbolo: )
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/b1qaGt

---

**Otras alternativas para las clases de caracteres**

En la respuesta usamos `[\d.]+` para números y `[-+*/()]` para un símbolo. Pero quizás te interesa algo más específico. Estas son algunas opciones que podrías intercambiar, según te convenga de acuerdo a tu caso:

- Un número que opcionalmente tiene decimales:

  ```
  \d+(?:\.\d+)?
  ```

  Acá no usamos una clase de caracteres (va sin corchetes).
- Un número que opcionalmente tiene decimales, y/u opcionalmente tiene un exponente:

  ```
  \d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:[eE]\d+)?
  ```

  Como String: `"\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?(?:[eE]\\d+)?"`
- En vez de buscar símbolos, podríamos buscar *todo lo que no es un número*:

  ```
  [^\d.]
  ```
- O, al revés, todo lo que no sea uno de los símbolos que estás usando:

  ```
  [^-+*/()]+
  ```
- O una forma más amplia de símbolos de puntuación (ojo que incluye al punto):

  ```
  \p{Punct}
  ```

  Coincide con uno de estos caracteres: `` !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~ ``.

  Como String: `"\\p{Punct}"`
- No usaría la categoría de Unicode [Symbol, Math](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Sm/list.htm), ya que no incluye a la mayoría de los símbolos "*comunes*" (sólo al `+` en tu ejemplo):

  ```
  \p{Sm}
  ```
- Pero podemos usar algo aún más genérico, cualquier símbolo o signo de puntuación, según las categorías Unicode Symbol y Punctuation:

  ```
  [\p{S}\p{P}]
  ```

  Como String: `"[\\p{S}\\p{P}]"`
- O inclusive, algo más entreverado, todos los símbolos o signos de puntuación excepto el punto (`.`):

  ```
  (?!\.)[\p{P}\p{S}]
  ```

  Como String: `"(?!\\.)[\\p{P}\\p{S}]"`
- O lo mismo (símbolos o signos excepto `.`) usando una [intersección](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-class-operations.html#intersection) en la clase de caracteres:

  ```
  [\p{S}\p{P}&&[^.]]
  ```

  Como String: `"[\\p{S}\\p{P}&&[^.]]"`.

Comment: Mariano de verdad, muchas gracias. La primera expresión funciona de maravilla. La segunda ("[\d.]+|[-+*/()]") no se usaría con split() ?

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, en verdad tu segunda solución es más rápida. Sos un campeón!

Comment: @boctulus Recién ahí terminé de agregar lo que quería para completar... Me alegro que te haya ayudado.

Answer (score 0):

en base a tu pregunta realize el siguiente código que te muestro a continuación

```
public class SplitApp {

public static void main(String... javierMS) {
    String cadena = "1000000.315|+|5.8|/|(|6.0|+|1|-|8|*|2.0|)"; // tu cadena con el separador "|"
    String[] extraccion = cadena.split("\\|",13); // metodo split con el separador + el limite en int

    for(String elemento : extraccion){ // impresion de la extraccion por medio de un for mejorado o for each
        System.out.println(elemento);   
    }

}
```

el resultado de la impresión es el siguiente:

```
1000000.315
+
5.8
/
(
6.0
+
1
-
8
*
2.0
)
```

espero que te sirva de ayuda, si tienes dudas me comentas saludos.

Comment: Agradezco el esfuerzo pero impones un pre-requisito de otro separador que no estaría presente en la expresión.