# ¿Cómo separar un String con una ecuación algebraica?

Tags: java, arraylist

Estoy intentando separar un `String` el cual va contener una expresión matemática como por ejemplo: `7x9+y/1.5`. El problema que tengo esta principalmente en los números de dos dígitos o decimales es decir me gustaría ir metiendo cada numero en un arreglo o un `ArrayList` como en el ejemplo anterior quedara algo así:

> nuevoArray={7,x,9,+,y,/,1.5}

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y que intentaste?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Cómo separar un String en Java. Cómo utilizar split()](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/45846/c%c3%b3mo-separar-un-string-en-java-c%c3%b3mo-utilizar-split)

Comment: @LautaroZarandon no porque si tuviera un solo símbolo, en este caso puedo tener un + - / * %

Comment: Ya intentaste usando expresiones regulares?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Qué significa esta expresión regular? (Referencia de expresiones regulares)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/223553/qu%c3%a9-significa-esta-expresi%c3%b3n-regular-referencia-de-expresiones-regulares)

Comment: Y también te recomiendo revisar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/127195/separar-expresi%c3%b3n-matem%c3%a1tica-con-expresiones-regulares-en-java

Answer (score -1):

En este caso... lo primero que hay que hacer es validar correctamente la entrada de la fórmula, en la que sólo permita ingresar dígitos, puntos (decimal) y signos...

Una mejora a este enunciado sería agregar símbolos de agrupación, ya que éstos también alterarían el resultado de una presunta fórmula...

Yo utilizaría un ciclo [for](/questions/tagged/for), que recorre el string extrayendo el `charAt(n)` y evaluando cada caracter, con un [switch](/questions/tagged/switch)...

y con este ciclo, se procedería ir añadiendo los valores al `string` separado por comas, como un acumulador += de `strings`.